# Liferay portlet: liferay friendly custom Url parameter

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

Can someone help me? I have custom parameter, "statusparam" for example. And I want to do something like this:

```
actionResponse.sendRedirect(redirect + "&statusparam=error");
```

But the problem is that custom parameter is non-friendly to liferay and liferay doesn't see it in my render method:

```
String status = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "statusparam");
```

How can I generate liferay-friendly URL with my custom parameters? Or how can I take them?

Comment: The problem is that your parameter must be in proper namespace of the portlet. How do you generate the `redirect` variable? If you use the [PortletURL](https://docs.liferay.com/portlet-api/2.0/javadocs/javax/portlet/PortletURL.html) (e.g. via [PortletURLUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/PortletURLUtil.html)), you can use the `setParameter(String name, String value)` method.

Comment: @jahra, Did you find suitable solution?

Answer (score 2):

**Pattern 1: setRenderParameter** 
One way is to set render parameter(s) in action phase using `setRenderParameter` as following:

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("statusparam", "error");
```

and then get using:

```
String status = renderRequest.getParameter("statusparam");
```

or

```
String status = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "statusparam");
```

**Pattern 2: Global property** 
Other way is to put a global property in action class, assign it value in action method then it would be accessible in render method as well.

```
public class MyPortletAction extends GenericPortlet {
    String statusparam = "";

    public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) {

        if(statusparam != ""){
            // Perform operation as per your requirement
        }
    }

    public void processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) {

        // Set statusparam here:
        statusparam = "error";
    }
}
```

**Pattern 3: queryString** 
While, if you want to pass it as `queryString` parameter, then you can extract it from `HttpServletRequest` object in render phase as following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest);
String statusparam = request.getParameter("statusparam");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to get parameter values which don't have namespace prefix.

1. Add following line in liferay-portal.xml :

   > < requires-namespaced-parameters > false < /
   >   requires-namespaced-parameters >

and you can read like:

```
String status = ParamUtil.getString(renderRequest, "statusparam");
```

2. Or use HttpServletRequest like:

> ```
> HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(renderRequest);
> String statusparam = request.getParameter("statusparam");
> ```

Edit: If you only need this parameter in **render method of same portlet**, use **setRenderParameter** like:

```
actionResponse.setRenderParameter("statusparam", "error");
```

Remember, it will not add in URL and also will not available in another portlets

Comment: Don't use **Pattern 2: Global property**  as @parkash-kumar explained in his answer. Each request don't have separate portlet object.

Comment: The question is not about the best way of fetching request parameters.

Comment: What if another user request come in action method between action and render phase of first request? It will override first value. Is it? No one create a portal application for single user

Comment: Another request of what? renderRequest / actionRequest??? If other request is of render the property will be empty for it. While if other request is for action, then the value will be set on certain condition. I don't see any over-ridden of property there.

Comment: How much experience do you have in liferay? Do you know singleton pattern? If object is singleton, how it will be empty in next request?

Comment: I am quite new to Liferay. I have never studied about Design Patterns. Thanks for your information.